# How to Instatiate only one object from Array in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to Instantiate only one object at a time, so I don't know what is wrong with my code because it instantiates all objects from the array at same time. With a random range, it is possible but I want to Instatiate it by order.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (timer > maxTime)
        {
           // Shuffle(enemies);

        //    RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
            float center = Screen.width / Screen.height;



            CreateEnemies(center);


          //  newEnemie = Instantiate(enemies[RandomNumber]);
          //   newEnemie.transform.position = transform.position+new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x -1.5f, screenBounds.x +1.5f), 0, 0);
          //  newEnemie.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x + 1.5f, screenBounds.x - 1.5f), 0, 0);


            timer = 0;


        }

        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    void Shuffle(GameObject[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject temp = array[i];
            int random = Random.Range(i, array.Length);
            array[i] = array[random];
            array[random] = temp;
        }
    }
    void CreateEnemies(float positionY)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++)
        {
            enemies[i] = Instantiate(enemies[i], transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x - 1.5f, screenBounds.x + 1.5f), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            positionY += 1f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should not use `for` loop then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create Enemies function does what is says, it instantiates enemies (plural). When the function is called it goes through the entire array and instantiate all enemies. If you only want 1 each time the function is called you could use something like this.

```
private int currentEnemyIndex = 0;//Enemy to spwan index

void CreateEnemies(float positionY)
{
    if (currentEnemyIndex < enemies.Length)//Make sure you don't go out of bound for your array. You could also clamp if you want to keep spwaning the last one.
    {
        enemies[currentEnemyIndex] = Instantiate(enemies[currentEnemyIndex], transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x - 1.5f, screenBounds.x + 1.5f), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        positionY += 1f;
        ++currentEnemyIndex;//Increment the enemy index so next call you spwan the next enemy.
    }
}
```